# nginx geoip city how to use English characters only?

Tags: nginx, geoip

I have a problem with national characters for showing geoipCity
I need to set header for proxy as a X-City, but I want to use english only characters, is there any option for language?

for example we have a city Tekirdağ, and in geoiplookup -l  I can see that there are english Tekirdag and in Turkish Tekirdağ, but $geoip_city variable gives me only city name in national characters :(

with Geoip2 documentation, it is possible to select default language on load geoip file,
but is that possible for regular geoip module?

Answer (score 0):

To understand how the data is structured within the `MMDB` file, just download the tool:

[mmdbinspect - github.com/maxmind/mmdbinspect](https://github.com/maxmind/mmdbinspect)

I recommend to get the binary from *releases* for your operating system, and then query your mmdb file with some ip.

In NGINX, just specify the path to the parameter.

E.g:

`./mmdbinspect_0.1.1_linux_386/mmdbinspect --db /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb 8.8.8.8`

and in NGINX conf:

(this is example for country, change accordingly for city.) 

`$geoip2_data_country_code source=$remote_addr country iso_code;`

In the above example the path is: `country.iso_code`